# Помогите тут легкий вопрос про чтение файла тхт и т.д

Tags: python

Есть некий файл file.txt там написано вотак

`2737373773 3 3` снизу нее
`2782838388 3 3` а снизу нее

```
5559824474 2 2
```

И переменная
Ss = 5559824474

Как сделать так, чтобы код проверил весь файл и со строкой, которая совпадает с переменной справа нее, первую `2` записал в переменную `s` а двойку, которая еще дальше в переменную `a`, и получилось
s=2
a=2

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ss = 5559824474

with open("input_file.txt") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        first, s, a = line.split()
        if first == str(Ss):
            print(s, a)
            break
    else:
        print("Такой строки в файле нет.")
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> 2 2
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. В цикле `for` читаем каждую строку вашего файла `input_file.txt` в переменную `line`.
2. Затем ее методом `.split()` разделим на 3 части.

   Для первой части применим любое имя, для остальных двух применим имена, которые вы хотели, т.е. `a` и `s`.
3. Теперь проверяем, если первая часть равна строке из числа `Ss` - тогда мы успели и (для теста) выводим значения переменных `a` и `s`.
   Командой `break` внезапно выходим из цикла. В переменных `a` и `s` остались желаемые значения.
4. Когда такой строки в файле нет, в ветви `else` сообщим об этом.

Comment: А я смогу потом дальше в коле использовать эти переменные?

Comment: @Да, естественно, я это сделал так, как вы хотели. Но в них не числа, а строки. Когда вы хотите, чтобы они были числовыми, нужно еще перевести их функцией `int()`: `s = int(s)` и `a = int(a)`.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо вам большое

Comment: @Рамазан, не стоит. Когда мой ответ был для вас полезным, вы можете принять его (клик на галочку возле него).

Comment: Прости если не сложно мне просто ограничили возможность задавать вопросы неверная из-за того что я плохо оформил их я бы хотел тебя спросить @bot.message_handler(commands=['utka'])
def ferma(message):
       Что тут написать чтобы бот считывал число после /utka [3] чтобы считал тройку и поместил в переменную q